# Unexpected behavior on Ticker interval change

Tags: go

I naively wrote a piece of code to change the interval of a `time.Ticker`, and upon reviewing it I am irritated that it works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    ticker := time.NewTicker(5 * time.Second)
    switcher := time.NewTimer(16 * time.Second)
    for {
        select {
        case <-ticker.C:
            fmt.Println("ticker " + time.Now().Format("15:04:05"))
        case <-switcher.C:
            fmt.Println("switching")
            ticker = time.NewTicker(1 * time.Second)
        }
    }
}
```

> $ go run main.go
>   ticker 02:19:03
>   ticker 02:19:08
>   ticker 02:19:13
>   switching
>   ticker 02:19:15
>   ticker 02:19:16
>   ticker 02:19:17

It does what I want, namely switch the frequency of the `ticker` Ticker to one second after 16 seconds. However, reading it again I would expect that after 16 seconds, a new Ticker object is created, while the `select` statement holds a reference to the channel of the old one, preventing it from garbage collection and keep on ticking every five seconds.

So why does this code change the ticker's frequency?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A `select` statement isn't a closure and doesn't "hold" a reference to anything.
You're simply replacing the value of `ticker`, and as you can see, the interval changes accordingly.